# Base64 encoded Xml inside Json: Xml tags are lost

Tags: xml, json, base64

I'm trying to process a json document in **javascript**. The critical part is that the Json document has a section carrying base64 encoded xml data.
if I take the base64 encoded data and try to decode them I'll see that the xml tags are trimmed away.

For example:

I have this base64 string in the json content section

`Jmx0O3RhZyZndDtjb250ZW50Jmx0Oy90YWcmZ3Q7`

If you try to decode it with every base64 tool you'll get

`<tag>content</tag>`

Instead, I only get

`content`

loosing the information from the xml tags. I really need them, any advice?

EDIT: you can see the **javascript** code below:

```
    var requestUrl = span.html();
    var data = JSON.parse(doAjaxGet(requestUrl));   //I get the json document
    if(data!=null)
    {
        var envelope = data.document.envelope[0]; 
        if(envelope!=null)
        {           
            if(envelope!=null)
            {
                var data = envelope.node.applicationData;
                if(data!=null)
                {
                    var li_d = ul.find('#data');
                    encodedData = data.value;
                    li_d.find('span').html(base64.decode(encodedData)); //here the encodeddata are decoded and the Xml tags are trimmed
                    li_d.show();
                }
```

and here's the Json

```
    {
       "document":{
          "envelope":[
             {
                "node":{
                   "applicationData":{
                      "value":"PGJpekxvY2F0aW9uPml0LnVuaWZpLmRldC50ZWxlbWF0LmVwY2lzLmRvY3VtZW50LklkZW50aWZpZXJANmRlZWE5NmM8L2JpekxvY2F0aW9uPg=="
                   }
                }
             }
          ]
       }
    }
```

in the following I'll include the the library I use to encode/decode, but I think it isn't helpful because if I do the steps:

1. copy the base64 payload form the json
2. paste it in the same js file I use to process the document as follows

`base64.decode('PGJpekxvY2F0aW9uPml0LnVuaWZpLmRldC50ZWxlbWF0LmVwY2lzLmRvY3VtZW50LklkZW50aWZpZXJANmRlZWE5NmM8L2JpekxvY2F0aW9uPg==')`

the output is correct i.e. I have the xml tag included in the decoded string. So I argue that the problems is related to the fact that I'm decoding something inside a json document.

By the way, here's the library

```
base64 = {

        // private property
        _keyStr : "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",

        // public method for encoding
        encode : function (input) {
            var output = "";
            var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
            var i = 0;

            input = base64._utf8_encode(input);

            while (i < input.length) {

                chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
                chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
                chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

                enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
                enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
                enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
                enc4 = chr3 & 63;

                if (isNaN(chr2)) {
                    enc3 = enc4 = 64;
                } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
                    enc4 = 64;
                }

                output = output +
                this._keyStr.charAt(enc1) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
                this._keyStr.charAt(enc3) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc4);

            }

            return output;
        },

        // public method for decoding
        decode : function (input) {
            var output = "";
            var chr1, chr2, chr3;
            var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
            var i = 0;

            input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

            while (i < input.length) {

                enc1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
                enc2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
                enc3 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
                enc4 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

                chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
                chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
                chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

                if (enc3 != 64) {
                    output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
                }
                if (enc4 != 64) {
                    output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
                }

            }

            output = base64._utf8_decode(output);

            return output;

        },

        // private method for UTF-8 encoding
        _utf8_encode : function (string) {
            string = string.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");
            var utftext = "";

            for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {

                var c = string.charCodeAt(n);

                if (c < 128) {
                    utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
                }
                else if((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
                    utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
                    utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
                }
                else {
                    utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
                    utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
                    utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
                }

            }

            return utftext;
        },

        // private method for UTF-8 decoding
        _utf8_decode : function (utftext) {
            var string = "";
            var i = 0;
            var c = c1 = c2 = 0;

            while ( i < utftext.length ) {

                c = utftext.charCodeAt(i);

                if (c < 128) {
                    string += String.fromCharCode(c);
                    i++;
                }
                else if((c > 191) && (c < 224)) {
                    c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);
                    string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 31) << 6) | (c2 & 63));
                    i += 2;
                }
                else {
                    c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);
                    c3 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+2);
                    string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 15) << 12) | ((c2 & 63) << 6) | (c3 & 63));
                    i += 3;
                }

            }

            return string;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Need more information. What language? Are you decoding with a built-in function, library function, homemade function? How is your json being parsed? (show us some code)

Comment: I edit the question to follow your suggestions

Comment: I'm not sure what library you're using, but is it correct to assume that `li_d.find('span').html(base64.decode(encodedData)); li_d.show();` is dropping the decoded string into a SPAN on the page?

Comment: @svidgen yes, it's correct. I want to put the decoded string in a span. Actually I'll have to manage it somehow but now it's fine to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm jumping the gun a little on my answer here. But, under the assumption that your answer to my last question is **yes** ...

Create or find a simple html escaping function and run the decoded data through it before dropping it on the page. For your purposes, I think it can be pretty simple.

```
var escapeTags = function(s) {
  return s.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt");
} // escapeTags()
```

Dropping it on the page doesn't change much:

```
li_d.find('span').html(escapeTags(base64.decode(encodedData)));
```

Comment: it's a clever answer but the problem here is that I may have a little bit complex xml structure. For examle if I have the following: <id>1876</id><rank>34</rank> I'll have the following decoded string: 187634 (the xml tags are eliminated) which makes data compromised.

Comment: No. This solution should show the XML precisely as it is in the node. Point is, the browser is parsing out the tags. So, you need to escape the angle brackets if/when you want the browser to show them.

Comment: If you run your script in Chrome or Safari and inspect the document immediately after your data is dropped in the SPAN, you'll likely see ID and RANK nodes. Evidence that they're **in** the resulting data string and just being treated as "regular" tags.

Comment: I drop the hat. You are right. So it wasn't an issue of any kind of json validation or postprocessing behind the courtains and stuff. It's just the browser! thanks!